# Send form serialize to asp.net webmethod

Tags: asp.net, jquery, serialization

The project continues . .

I have a form that I'm serializing with the jquery form plugin. Works great.

I am then using the jquery ajax feature to post to an asp.net web method so that each form element can be inserted into a database.

My issue is this, how do I loop through each of the request.form params that is sent via ajax in the asp.net web method. If I use a standard Request.Form("") I receive an error. Here is my code.

```
var queryString = $('input').fieldSerialize(); 

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Detail.aspx/doPostTest",
   data: "{ 'txtQuery': '" + queryString + "'}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
        var products = eval(data.d);                             
        console.log(products);
   }
});
```

**Code behind**

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function doPostTest(ByVal txtQuery As String) As String

    'Grab Request Form variables
    Request.Form("txtMember")
End Function
```

The error I receive on the server side is the following:

> Cannot refer to an instance member of
>   a class from within a shared method or
>   shared member . . etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to call `HttpContext.Current.Request` to access your current `HttpRequest` from static methods.

The `Page` class your page inherits from contains an instance property `Request`; therefore it's not possible to access this prop from your static methods.