# Become very Confused Posting a Form to a Web Method with jQuery

Tags: vb.net, forms, jquery, form-submit

I have a form which contains a fairly large number of values. I am currently submitting with a POST method, but I wish to convert this to do it with jQuery via AJAX.

I have been experimenting with converting my code-behind "save to database" function into a Web Method. I am using a two-step function method, firstly preparing all the variables from Request.Form("parameterName") and then passing them all into a "saveData" function as follows:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub prepareRequestFormValues()
    /// save to database and do stuff with the variables
    variableName = HttpContext.Current.Request("parameterName")
    saveToDatabase(list, of, form, variables, ...)
End Sub
```

Having read this post [Send form serialize to asp.net webmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966763/send-form-serialize-to-asp-net-webmethod)

I can see that using the jQuery forms plugin I can serialize the whole form and send it as a single variable to the processing code.

However, I have got myself completely confused now. Given that I am pretty new to AJAX/codebehind and so on I've been going round in circles and now am very confused!

Using

```
var queryString = $('input').fieldSerialize(); 

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Detail.aspx/doPostTest",
   data: "{ 'txtQuery': '" + queryString + "'}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
        var products = eval(data.d);                             
        console.log(products);
   }
});
```

From the post mentioned above, I can see I can send this string, but how do I process it server-side when recieved? The article implied that `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("parameterName")` should work, but it doesn't... I'm guessing because I need to access it from the txtQuery variable.... but.... I'm lost I am afraid!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [really good tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/160/create-a-ajax-based-form-submission-with-jquery) containing the JS to do this. Instead of posting to PHP post to your aspx page. Here is [an forum post with a similar question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1696477.aspx/1?Ajax%20jQuery%20and%20VB%20Net). XIII had posted the follwoing code.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#btnAddToCart').click(function () {
            var result = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "PassInParameterAndUpdateSession.aspx/AddProductToCart",
                data: '{ pID: "1833", qty: "13", lblType: "1" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: succeeded,
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                },
                error: function (xhr, err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function succeeded(msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    }

</script>
```

And your WebMethod

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services

    Namespace aspnetforums.AjaxAndSession
        <ScriptService> _
        Public Partial Class PassInParameterAndUpdateSession
            Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
            Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                Session("test") = ""
            End Sub

            <WebMethod> _
            Public Shared Function AddProductToCart(pID As String, qty As String, lblType As String) As String
                Dim selectedProduct As String = String.Format("+ {0} - {1} - {2}", pID, qty, lblType)

                HttpContext.Current.Session("test") += selectedProduct

                Return HttpContext.Current.Session("test").ToString()
            End Function
        End Class
End Namespace
```